# RDLC format number function

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc

I have values in a db:

```
10.4
33
42.87
1.01
22.1
8
```

I know I can format numbers in my RDLC reports, however, how can I make sure that the output of the data will always be:

```
10.40
33.00
42.87
1.01
22.10
8.00
```

you will notice that I need to show two decimal points, even if the number has none,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Argh.... google helped, it is quite simple:

```
=FormatNumber(Fields!SomeField.Value,2)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `Format` property of your `TextBox`; for example:

```
Format = "f2"
```

Using Format you can use *"c"* to format currency (i.e. `"c2"`).

Comment: thanx... the more options the better.

Comment: sorry OOT.... But what if we want to change from number to formatcurrency...? Where we found the country list code actually @tezzo?

Answer (score 3):

Right click that Control[TextBox] in RDLC, TextBox Properties, SelectNumber,CAtegory-Number , See Decimal Places is 2, Click Ok.

Comment: OR directly set the format of that control as 0.00;0.00

Answer (score 1):

```
FormatCurrency(Expression as object, NumDigitsAfterZero as tristate, IncludingLeadingDigit as tristate, UwseParenseForNegativeNumbers as tristate, GroupDigits as tristate) as string
```

I tried using the Number tab settings for the placeholder and that didn't do anything. The above works.

Answer (score 0):

```js
ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[3];
param[0] = new ReportParameter("LumpsumDiscount", lumpsumdiscount.ToString(), false);
param[1] = new ReportParameter("PaymentDetailType", paymenttype, false);
param[2] = new ReportParameter("ChargesAmount", Samount.ToString(), false);
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);
```

**Now:**

chargesAmount showing 28000.0000 instead of 28000.00